The textile factory and spinning machine in John Dyer’s “The Fleece”
In book 3 of The Fleece (1757), John Dyer describes a textile factory in the Calder Valley in Yorkshire, which has a water-powered spinning machine:

                        We next are shown
A circular machine, of new design,
In conic shape: it draws and spins a thread
Without the tedious toil of needless hands.
A wheel, invisible, beneath the floor,
To ev’ry member of th’ harmonious frame
Gives necessary motion. One, intent,
O’erlooks the work: the carded wool, he says,
Is smoothly lapp’d around those cylinders,
Which, gently turning, yield it to yon cirque
Of upright spindles, which, with rapid whirl
Spin out, in long extent, an even twine.
John Dyer (1757). The Fleece, book 3, lines 291–302. London: R. and J. Dodsley.

What machine is Dyer describing in this passage? It is too early to be a spinning frame (1760s) or spinning mule (1770s). Can the factory be identified?

The spinning jenny slightly precedes the frame and mule you mention, but still too late (1760s). It replaced something with a horizontal wheel, its origin story showing how Hargreaves realised the wheel could be vertical instead, but I can't find much information about the horizontal-wheel machine that preceded it. The water frame is also too late (1760s). Water-powered beetling machines existed earlier, but can't be what's described here.

The spinning jenny was hand-powered.

As noted in the question, the poem's date of 1757 predates the invention of the spinning frame and the spinning mule. This would seem to indicate that the machine would have been a "roller spinning machine", an invention that was patented by Lewis Paul and John Wyatt in 1738. According to the wikipedia article:

This principle [roller spinning] was the basis of Richard Arkwright's
later water frame design. By 1742 Paul and Wyatt had opened a mill in
Birmingham which used their new rolling machine powered by a donkey,
this was not profitable and soon closed. A factory was opened in
Northampton in 1743, with fifty spindles turning on five of Paul and
Wyatt's machines, proving more successful than their first mill; this
operated until 1764.

Further evidence can be found in an article from 1921 by Alfred Seymour-Jones, entitled "The Invention of Roller Drawing in Cotton Spinning". Seymour-Jones notes that "a poem, written by John Dyer entitled 'The Fleece'"

gives us an excellent description of Paul's second construction
contained in his 1738 patent, and of his invention patented in 1758. He
fixes the engines by his footnotes as being Paul's patents.

I cannot independently verify it, but Seymour-Jones quotes Dyer's footnote to the poem as reading:

A circular machine, - a most curious machine, invented by Mr Paul. It
is at present contrived to spin cotton; but it may be made to spin
fine carded wool.

It thus seems reasonably certain that the machine described in the poem was one of Paul and Wyatt's roller spinning machines. The wikipedia article also corroborates this point, stating:

Rev John Dyer of Northampton recognised the importance of the Paul and
Wyatt cotton spinning machine in a poem in 1757

the poem being, of course, "The Fleece".
This deals with the first part of the question ("What kind of machine was Dyer describing?"), but the second part ("Can the factory be identified?") is more difficult. Paul-Wyatt machines were described as being installed at Birmingham, Northampton, and Leominster, but there is no mention of Calder Valley. In The Cotton Trade and Industrial Lancashire, 1600-1780 by A.P. Wadsworth (available on preview at google books) the author lists the various installations of these machines, and notes that:

The well-known account by the poet Dyer, who represents it as erected
in a workhouse in Yorkshire and spinning wool, is a pious hope rather
than a statement of fact.

and that Dyer's footnote regarding the possibility, rather than a reality, of adapting the machine to spin wool, as being further evidence against the mill actually existing.

Wow, nice work! I spent ages researching this question and couldn't find an answer. Only one suggestion: is it possible to find a picture of the roller spinning machine, to see how well the poem described it?

There is an oft-copied image from the patent, but it's quite unclear what it actually represents. Seymour-Jones includes a verbal description from the patent, which does seem reasonably consistent with Dyer's description (but no picture!).
